# Trying to get the value of an updated array outside of an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, oop

In the `function changing()` below I'm trying get the value of the array arr[0] and output some info related to the array value. I guess the problem is that the arr is not being updated. I need to update this array that is outside the events so I could use the value like in the function. how can I do this? Im learning about pub/sub and .trigger() so if you can give result pertaining to that style that would be great

```
arr = []
$('body').on("clicked", function () {
    // $(".clickMe").on("click", function(){
    if ($('#thisBox')[0].checked) {
        $('#thisBox').prop('checked', false);
        data = false;
        console.log(data)
        arr[0] = (data)
        console.log(arr)
    } else {
        $('#thisBox').prop('checked', true);
        // console.log(prop('checked'))
        data = true;
        console.log(data)
        arr[0] = data
        console.log(arr)
    }
    // });
});
console.log("outside" + arr)

function changing() {
    $('body').trigger("clicked");
    if (arr[0] == undefined) {
        $(".output").html("set undefined")
    } else if (arr[0] == true) {
        $(".output").html("set true")
    } else if (arr[0] == false) {
        $(".output").html("set false")
    }
}
changing()

$(".secondClick").on("click", function () {
    $('body').trigger("clicked");
    if (arr[0] == true) {
        $("body").css("backgroundColor", 'blue')
    } else if (arr[0] == false) {
        $("body").css("backgroundColor", 'green')
    }
})
```

Comment: What's #thisBox ??? maybe you could make a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net so you can help you better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qnounnj2/

Comment: @James where do you see an asynchronous call?

Comment: "I guess the problem is that the arr is not being updated" -> It updates perfectly in your fiddle, I get `[true]` then `[false]` then `[true]`...

Comment: Would help if you were more specific about where exactly in your code you think you have issues and what steps in the UI would create those issues

Comment: well i want to change the .output. html() to the associated string if arr[o] == false, the text on the screen should be "set false" for example `function changing()` is not receiving the updates I think. I need the updates outside  of an event

Comment: That description is not very concise. Suggest you update question with what expected results are and steps to reproduce issues. Text in question is very vague

Comment: what is not specific? I want the text of the element "output" to say the appropriate string. do you understand that?

Comment: @jeremy. ok the array gets updated, but that is not proven in the  'changing()'  function. how can I make it so the updates can be displayed in a function outside of an event

Comment: I don't understand anything. It just doesn't make sense. You don't update "inside" or "outside" an event. An event just happens, like "someone saying hello", and a function can be triggered when that event happens. So you can update your array in a function, not in an event. I don't understand _"that is not proven in the 'changing()' function"_ either.

Comment: I'm new to this so If you can help me understand that would be awesome. I updated an array when I clicked on .secondClick by triggering "clicked" which is an event that has a fnc that sets arr[0] = to either true or false. correct? since I set the value of the array inside the functions that is inside the event. I would think that inside the changing function() I would be able to access the array that is in the global scope. I see that I cant do that because in the events fn I am changing the array, but in the changing() function the .output el html doesnt change according to condition sry.

Comment: another question I asked, but it's more about theory
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836606/trying-to-understanding-custom-events-using-jquery-to-separate-the-events-from-a

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code you want looks something more like this. The code is self commented

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnounnj2/3/)

```js
/*Click handles change colors button*/
$('.secondClick').click(function () {
    /*sets checked to a boolean of the checkbox*/
    var checked = $('#thisBox').prop('checked');
    /*executes function*/
    change(checked);
});
/*Handles alternate colors button*/
$('.alternateClick').click(function () {
    /*Sets the checkbox opposite of what the checkbox was*/
    $('#thisBox').prop('checked',!$('#thisBox').prop('checked'));
    /*sets checked to a boolean of the checkbox*/
    var checked = $('#thisBox').prop('checked');
    /*executes function*/
    change(checked);
});

/*takes a boolean to change body color*/
function change(myBoolean) {
    if (myBoolean) {
        $("body").css("backgroundColor", 'blue');
    } else {
        $("body").css("backgroundColor", 'green')
    }
}
/*initiates the first change events so the page
is green on first page run.*/
change($('#thisBox').prop('checked'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="thisBox" type="checkbox"></input>
<button class="secondClick">Change Colors</button>
<button class="alternateClick">Alternate Colors</button>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. This is away to do it without using arrays, but I was trying to learn how to update arrays after an event and use the array values throughout my project like what I was trying to do in the code in my questions. I'm starting to think It's not possible and I have to change the way I think but I really think it is possible. through bub sub possibly using .trigger() and .on() but every time I try do it I get stuck.